# Adding content via :hover:before causes base element to disappear on mouse out

Tags: css, google-chrome, hover, opera, css-tables

I'm trying to create a card tile with a background image (sprites). On hover, I would like to swap the background image with a color and add some text. I'm trying to position this text (which can be 1, 2 or even 3 lines) in the very center of the tile. To do this, I'm setting the base element to display: table and the `:before` element to `display: table-cell` (but only on hover).

The problem that I'm facing is, after one has hovered the base element and moused out, the base element disappears in Chrome and Opera on a Mac! (Works fine in FF and Safari. Untested in IE or any of these browsers on Windows/Linux). Here's my code and a fiddle:

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/stacigh/0vf47vy5/

```css
.picture {
    outline: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
    width: 150px !important;
    height: 150px !important;
    background: maroon  url('http://www.placehold.it/150x150');
    cursor: pointer;
    display: table;
}  
.picture:hover {
    background-image: none;
    color: white;
}
.picture:hover:before {
    content: 'Test';
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
        
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle; 
}
```

```html
<div class="picture"></div>
<div class="picture"></div>
<div class="picture"></div>
<div class="picture"></div>
<div class="picture"></div>
<div class="picture"></div>
<div class="picture"></div>
<div class="picture"></div>
```

Edit:
Here's a gif with the behavior
[image: Quirky behavior with :hover:before pseudo elements]

Comment: Ummmm... yeah.. does not happen to me in Chrome 39.0.2171.71 m -- that is, not in the Fiddle you linked.

Comment: I see it here on 37.0.2062.103. I'd report it to Chrome. You can [toggle between `block` and `table`](http://jsfiddle.net/0vf47vy5/3/) on `:hover` to get the functionality you're needing, provided the initial state doesn't need it in your real project

Comment: What version of Chrome are you on Zach? I just updated Chrome and now it's working as expected. And of course I ended up re-copying something so I lost the version number I was most recently using. 38.something. Opera's still not working though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When checked in Chrome mac, adding a table-cell element dynamically causes the layout to break.

One thing that we can do is, we can add the element by default and update its content on hover.

http://jsfiddle.net/0vf47vy5/5/

```
.picture:before {
  content: '';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle; 
}

.picture:hover:before {
  content: 'Test';
}
```

This is working finr in Chrome MAC.

Comment: This is great. Works perfectly in both browsers that had the problem. Don't know why I didn't try this. Makes total sense. Thanks :)